# Crash when opening email composer

Tags: java, android, email

Every time I try to write a text into email composer I get a crash with this message.

Could someone help me with this error?

```
  E/AndroidRuntime(12948): Process: com.samsung.android.email.composer, PID: 12948

    > E/AndroidRuntime(12948): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class com.samsung.android.email.composer.htmleditor.ToolBarView
    > E/AndroidRuntime(12948): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    > E/AndroidRuntime(12948): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Comment: post some code, so that we can understand.